Show that $f_k$ has no continuous limit function
Let be $f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ where $f_n(x):=\begin{cases}0,&x\in \left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]\\n\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right),&x\in\left[\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\right]\\1,&x\in\left[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n},1\right].\end{cases}$ We consider the normed space $(\mathcal{C}([0,1]),\Vert\cdot\Vert_1)$, where $\Vert f\Vert_1:=\int\limits_0^1|f(x)|dx$.
Show that the sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ doesn't converge.

My apporach
We assume that there exists a limit $f$, i.e. for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an index $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\Vert f_n-f\Vert_1<\varepsilon$ for all $n>n_0$.
It follows
$$
\int\limits_0^{\frac{1}{2}}|f_n(x)-f(x)|dx=\int\limits_0^{\frac{1}{2}}|\hat{0}-f(x)|dx\leq \Vert f_n-f\Vert_1<\varepsilon\implies f(x)=0,
$$
for all $x\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$ because $f$ is a continuous function.
On the other hand we have that
$$
\int\limits_{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}}^1|f_n(x)-f(x)|dx=\int\limits_{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}}^1|\hat{1}-f(x)|dx\leq \Vert f_n-f\Vert_1<\varepsilon\implies f(x)=1,
$$
for all $x\in\left[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n},1\right]$ because $f$ is a continuous function. This implies $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in\left(\frac{1}{2},1\right]$. If we combine this result with first conclusion it means that $f$ is not continuous at $\frac{1}{2}$ which is a contraction. Consequentially, $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ cannot have a limit.

I had discussion with my tutor and she tried to explain that my conclusion "This implies $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in\left(\frac{1}{2},1\right]$" is not always true. I asked her several times to explain the exact reason why it fails in general but I have to admit that I did not fully understand her and finally gave up asking... Maybe someone else can explain what is wrong with this step?

@EricLey what exactly do you mean by "control the integral over $[1/2,1/2\pm 1/n]$"?

Are you sure it was that step in particular? "$f(x) = 1$ for all $x \in \left[\frac 12 + \frac 1n, 1\right]$" is the statement I'd say you haven't justified.
